# How to add a default constraint to a nullable column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wanted to add default values to a nullable field in SQL Server. I used the following t-sql

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblMain ADD  CONSTRAINT [default_0]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Sum]
```

This constraint will change any new values added to the Sum field in the tblMain table to 0 but it does not change the null values that was already in the column to 0.

I also tried the `WITH VALUES` option

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblMain ADD  CONSTRAINT [default_0]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Sum]  WITH VALUES
```

This did not change anything.

I know I can add the constraint and do something like:

```
UPDATE dbo.tblMain set Sum = 1 where Sum is null
```

But I want to know if I can do it using constraint in one scoop.

Comment: A constraint is used to prevent bad data from getting in, it does not update existing data. Also, keep in mind that a default constraint on a nullable column does NOT prevent NULL from being added. You can still get NULL if you don't include that column in your insert.

Comment: As Sean said - Default constraints will not change existing data.  What I would do in this situation (if constantly updating NULLs is not desirable) is to create a view with an `ISNULL(<yourfield>,0)`

Comment: or alter the column - first update to replace nulls with values, then alter the column to not null. this should be done inside a transaction with isolation level serializable.